# R - Create new columns based on different conditions of one column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse, data-manipulation

seeking some expertise/guidance on creating new columns in a data frame based on different conditions of one column.

My data frame is pretty huge, but I've subsetted it for easier reference. It's a feedback from animal lovers on their cost.

| Feedback | Cost | pig |
| --- | --- | --- |
| cat, dog, rabbit | 90 | 100 |
| cat & rabbit | 60 | 100 |
| cat and fish | 50 | 100 |
| dog/pig/rabbit | 250 | 100 |
| cat, pig | 200 | 100 |
| fish, rabbit, dog | 150 | 100 |
| dog, cat and pig | 260 | 100 |

```
df = structure(list(Feedback = c("cat, dog, rabbit", "cat & rabbit ", 
                                 "cat and fish", "dog/pig/rabbit", "cat, pig", "fish, rabbit, dog", 
                                 "dog, cat and pig"), Cost = c(90L, 80L, 50L, 300L, 200L, 120L, 
                                 260L), pig = c(100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L)), 
                                 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Does anyone know how I can create new columns based on the animals in the Feedback columns dplyr or tidyverse functions?

Currently I'm using ifelse() and it's not feasible should the dataframe gets larger.

The conditions are that

1. Cost of pig is fixed at 100.
2. Cost of remaining animals can be equally divided. However should pig exist, I have to subtract 100 from the total cost before dividing equally.
3. Needing to account for the special characters in Feedback column to separate the animals.

The ideal output should be as follows:

| Feedback | Cost | pig | cat | dog | rabbit | fish | pig_new |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| cat, dog, rabbit | 90 | 100 | 30 | 30 | 30 | 0 | 0 |
| cat & rabbit | 60 | 100 | 30 | 0 | 30 | 0 | 0 |
| cat and fish | 50 | 100 | 25 | 0 | 0 | 25 | 0 |
| dog/pig/rabbit | 250 | 100 | 0 | 75 | 75 | 0 | 100 |
| cat, pig | 200 | 100 | 100 | 100 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| fish, rabbit, dog | 150 | 100 | 0 | 50 | 50 | 50 | 0 |
| dog, cat and pig | 260 | 100 | 80 | 80 | 0 | 0 | 100 |

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the logic, we could do

```
library(dplyr)# version >= 1.1.0
library(stringr)
library(fastDummies)
dummy_cols(df, "Feedback", split = "\\s*[,&/]\\s*|\\s*and\\s*") %>% 
  rename_with(~ str_replace(str_remove(.x, "Feedback_"), "pig", "new_pig"), 
     starts_with("Feedback_")) %>%
  mutate(cnt = rowSums(pick(cat:dog)),
   across(cat:dog, ~ case_when(.x== 1 & new_pig == 0 ~ Cost/cnt, .x == 1 & 
    new_pig == 1 ~ (Cost - pig)/cnt, TRUE ~ 0)), 
   new_pig = pig * new_pig, cnt = NULL)
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Never knew of the fastDummies package, thanks for sharing!